# Promblem to use iradon on image with the shape of (168,400)

Tags: python, image, image-processing, tomography-reconstruction

I want to implement iradon. Radon image shape is (168,400).
But when I implement iradon on it the image shape become (168,168)!!!
I want to have an image with (168,400) shape.
Where is the problem?

```
Image = iradon (radon_image, filter_name=None)
```

I read the instruction on:
https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.iradon
; but I did not understand the problem.
I really appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: If you read the documentation, surely you noticed the `output_size` argument???

Comment: I insist: the output of radon should not, and is generally not, the same size as the output of iradon. Enforcing this makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be mis-understanding how the Radon (and inverse Radon) transform work.

The size of your `radon_image` is (number of pixels in original image, number of projections). So in your example, the image is 168 pixels across with 400 different projections (see image below from the [scikit-image website](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/transform/plot_radon_transform.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-transform-plot-radon-transform-py)). Therefore, when you perform the inverse Radon transform you will get an image with a size of 168 pixels.

Perhaps if you explain further why you want the resulting image with a particular size, it will be possible to help further.

[image: img]

Comment: Actually I want to multiply  the out put of iradon to the original image whose dimensions are (168x400)(iterative reconstruction). But I get the following error:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (168,400) (168,168)

Comment: @taherehzare the output of `iradon` and `radon` should be different sizes, mostly. Are you multiplying the right thing?

Comment: Yes. I sure that I multiply the right things. But I don't know what the problem really is. I have to check more closely.